# SharePoint - Syncing a View

Tags: sharepoint

In SharePoint, can you sync to your computer a certain "view" of files instead of all the documents in a document library?

I'll be having a document library with thousands of files and I only want a certain amount of them (a view) to download (sync) to my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Sync to Outlook or w/ OneDrive sync's everything in a folder that you have access to (not drafts by others, unpublished, etc). You can search for subsets and save those searches through explorer or Outlook, but it will still bring over all of the files to either location.